# Is it possible to define a minimum width for a Chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension for Chrome and have run into a problem with controlling the size of the popup window. I would like the user to not be able to shrink the window below a certain size. I'm using **Chrome's Manifest V3** and **popup** type.

I've tried applying CSS styles directly in the HTML file, but the window can still be resized to the minimum width.

Also tried using [onBoundsChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#event-onBoundsChanged). It works, but it's a bit weird. It allows you to shrink the window and then suddenly sets it to the desired width.

```js
  chrome.windows.onBoundsChanged.addListener(async (currentWindow) => {
    const { height = 0, width = 0 } = currentWindow;

    if (height < 800 || width < 400) {
      await extension.windows.update(currentWindowId!, {
        width: 400,
        height: 800,
      });
    }
  });
```

Also thought of doing it via `setInterval`. But the result is the same, the window can be shrunk and then it suddenly becomes normal.

```js
  setInterval(async () => {
    const currentWindow = await extension.windows.getCurrent();
    const { height = 0, width = 0 } = currentWindow;

    if (height < 800 || width < 400) {
      await extension.windows.update(currentWindowId!, {
        height: 800,
        width: 400,
      });
    }
  }, 500);
```

Maybe there are some other options to prevent the user from shrinking the window?

Comment: Try window.onresize listener inside the window.